# how to make responsive hexagon with 6 and 8 triangles

Tags: css

I found a code on codepen like this and here is the link : https://codepen.io/FStop/pen/uvenj

how to make this with 6 and 8 triangles?

```
<div class="hexagon">
  <div class="triangle"></div>
  <div class="triangle"></div>
  <div class="triangle"></div>
  <div class="triangle"></div>
  <div class="triangle"></div>
  <div class="triangle"></div>
  <div class="triangle"></div>
</div>
```

you can see css code on codepen link...I couldnt paste here...its very hard to ask something here

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean how to make eight triangles out of these six?
In case you mean that just add two more div elements with the class "triangle" and play around with the numbers. The `rotation` has to be `45deg` because you have eight triangles now (360:8) and the `width` must fit with the numbers of triangles you have now.
After playing around a little I got following solution:

HTML:

```
<div class="hexagon">
  <div class="triangle"></div>
  <div class="triangle"></div>
  <div class="triangle"></div>
  <div class="triangle"></div>
  <div class="triangle"></div>
  <div class="triangle"></div>
  <div class="triangle"></div>
  <div class="triangle"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body{
  padding: 25px;
}

@mixin hexagon($width: 100px, $color: #19c, $dir: down){
  // Math for calculating the height of equilateral triangle
  // Rounding this up helps a little with sub pixel rendering BS
  $height: ceil($width*(sqrt(3))/2);
  height: $height;
  width: $width;
  position: relative;
  // might as well center the thing
  margin: 0 auto;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform: translateX($width/2) rotate(30deg);
  .triangle{
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: $height/3 $width/8.5 0;
    border-color: #19c transparent;
    transform-origin: $width/8.5 $height/3 + 2;
    // Sass function to auto generate rotation
    $deg: 45deg;
    @for $i from 1 through 7{
      &:nth-child(#{$i}){
        transform: rotate(#{$deg});
      }
      $deg: $deg + 45;
    }
    &:nth-child(5), &:nth-child(6){
      border-color: lighten(#19c,25%) transparent;
    }
    &:nth-child(2), &:nth-child(3){
      border-color: darken(#19c,10%) transparent;
    }
  }
}

.hexagon{
  @include hexagon(300px);
}
```

[codePen Example](https://codepen.io/CeyKie/pen/KqpjJY)